# BottomSheetDialogFragment behaviour disorder when added nested fragment in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I've a BottomSheetDialogFragment inside a RecyclerView, when is clicked a button BottomSheet is showing. BottomSheetDialog expanding when scrolling down and collapsing when scroll finished on top normally.

[image]

But when I place the RecyclerView inside a fragment and lay the fragment to BottomSheetDialog; BottomSheet behaviours not working on the fragment, only works RecyclerView scrolling. On the other hand the behaviours work other places on BottomSheet. How to enable the behaviours as in the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check that your container layout has `app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">` and check that any listener/event you define extra, otherwise BottomSheetDialog normally behaive as you expect.

Comment: I've enabled nested scroll on recyclerview and solved, thanks.